# How do I set up VSCode to edit typescript targeting ES3 and using custom @types?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Context: **NOT** node. Rather, I'm targeting a C# wrapper around JScript (ES3 mostly.) So I don't want to use explicit export/import technologies. I just want my d.ts files to be parsed and used in VSCode to resolve symbols.

I'm trying to separate my custom types from my source folder but am finding that VSCode now can't "see" the types and so marks the types as unknown.

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es3",
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "ScriptHost"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "typeRoots": [
            "../RulesetRunner_Declarations",
            "../RI_Declarations"
        ],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "traceResolution": true,
        "listFilesOnly": true,
    }
}
```

In the next level up in the folder hierarchy there are folders `RI_Declarations` and `RulesetRunner_Declarations`. Each has a `@types` folder and a set of `.d.ts` files tied into `index.d.ts` with `/// <reference path="blah blah">` tags. E.g.

```
C:\Users\bugma\Source\Repos\Present\Scripts\RI_Declarations\@types>type Iterator.d.ts
declare var Iterator: (a: any) => void;
```

Annoyingly, despite the fact that two folders are declared in `typeRoots`, only the first is processed.

Below is what I get from running `tsc` on the command line.

```
======== Resolving type reference directive '@types', containing file 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/ts2rr/__inferred type names__.ts', root directory 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations,C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RI_Declarations'. ========
Resolving with primary search path 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations, C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RI_Declarations'.
Found 'package.json' at 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations/@types/package.json'.
'package.json' does not have a 'typesVersions' field.
'package.json' does not have a 'typings' field.
'package.json' has 'types' field './index.d.ts' that references 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations/@types/index.d.ts'.
File 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations/@types/index.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations/@types/index.d.ts', result 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations/@types/index.d.ts'.
======== Type reference directive '@types' was successfully resolved to 'C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations/@types/index.d.ts' with Package ID 'types/index.d.ts@1.0.0', primary: true. ========
C:/Users/bugma/scoop/persist/nodejs-lts/bin/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
C:/Users/bugma/scoop/persist/nodejs-lts/bin/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.scripthost.d.ts
C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/ts2rr/foo.ts
C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/ts2rr/ts2ly.ts
C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/ts2rr/ts2ri.ts
C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/ts2rr/ts2rr.ts
C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/ts2rr/types/@types/index.d.ts
C:/Users/bugma/Source/Repos/Present/Scripts/RulesetRunner_Declarations/@types/index.d.ts
```

So problems are:

1. RI_Declarations isn't being loaded
2. VSCode is not resolving any of the `typeRoots` and listing the various functions in them as unknown. I'm using the `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` extension in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

My work around is as follows:

- In my source folder I have a subfolder called "types". Into this I put [JUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/junction) links to folders that contain the `@types` folders that I want to reference.
- In my `tsconfig.json` I have

```
  "include": [
    "*.ts",
    "./types"
  ]
```

which causes VSCode to parse the `declare` statements therein.

I expect that I will still have to include a `typeRoots` so that compilation works. Currently the compilation (which involves running `tsc` and then renaming the resulting `.js` files to `.rr` or `.ri`) process complains about the symbols that VSCode can see but `tsc` can't.